# Observable type error from ngrx selector that returns multiple types

Tags: angular, typescript, types, observable, ngrx

I am able to assign the result of a  Typescript function which returns multiple types to a variable with a single type, as per the pseudo-code below:

```
export class MyComponent {
    aNumber: number;
    numberOrString(returnNumber: boolean): number | string {
        if (returnNumber === true) {
            return 5;
        } else {
            return 'Five';
        }
    }
    constructor(){
        this.aNumber = this.numberOrString(true) as number; 
    }
}
```

A type error is thrown if 'as number' is omitted from the line in the constructor.

How can I do the same thing, but with an ngrx selector that returns multiple possible types? E.g. the following:

```
aNumber$: Observable<number>;
this.aNumber$ = this.store$.pipe(select(numberOrString, { returnNumber: true }));
```

Throws a type error unless I define aNumber$ as:

```
aNumber$: Observable<number | string>;
```

But it's only ever going to be a number in this context and I want to set the type accordingly.

OR should I have two different selectors which each return a single type?

Comment: can you share the selector code?

Answer (score 0):

The RxJs map operator allows you to assign a type to the response, e.g:

```
aNumber$: Observable<number>;
this.aNumber$ = this.store$.pipe(select(numberOrString, { returnNumber: true }),map(response => response as number));
```

HOWEVER I've discovered that ngrx memoization can then add a further layer of complexity. All considered, I'm going to have a single return type per selector.